# How to get two pthread threads to respond to each others' wait and signal conditions?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a basic two-thread arrangement working.

I am reading a chunk of bytes into memory from `stdin` in one "producer" thread, and processing those bytes in a second "consumer" thread, once those bytes are available. Once the bytes are consumed, the consumer thread goes back to being dormant and the producer thread gets running again.

I am using `pthread_cond_wait()` and `pthread_cond_signal()` to have the two threads communicate to each other that data are produced or consumed.

Here is the code for the two threads:

```
void * produce_bytes(void *t_data)
{ 
    pthread_data_t *d = (pthread_data_t *)t_data;

    do {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&d->input_lock);
        d->n_bytes = fread(d->in_buf, sizeof(unsigned char), BUF_LENGTH_VALUE, stdin);
        if (d->n_bytes > 0) { 
            fprintf(stdout, "PRODUCER ...signaling consumer...\n");
            pthread_cond_signal(&d->input_cond);
            fprintf(stdout, "PRODUCER ...consumer signaled...\n");
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&d->input_lock);
    } while (d->n_bytes > 0);

    return NULL;
}

void * consume_bytes(void *t_data) 
{
    pthread_data_t *d = (pthread_data_t *)t_data;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&d->input_lock);
    while (d->n_bytes == 0)
        pthread_cond_wait(&d->input_cond, &d->input_lock);
    fprintf(stdout, "CONSUMER ...consuming chunk...\n");
    d->n_bytes = 0;
    fprintf(stdout, "CONSUMER ...chunk consumed...\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&d->input_lock);
}
```

The `pthread_data_t` is a struct I use to keep track of state:

```
typedef struct {
    pthread_mutex_t input_lock;
    pthread_cond_t input_cond;
    unsigned char in_buf[BUF_LENGTH_VALUE];
    size_t n_bytes;
} pthread_data_t;
```

I configure variables in my `main()` function; here is the relevant excerpt:

```
pthread_t producer_thread = NULL;
pthread_t consumer_thread = NULL;
pthread_data_t *thread_data = NULL;

thread_data = malloc(sizeof(pthread_data_t));
thread_data->n_bytes = 0;
pthread_mutex_init(&(thread_data->input_lock), NULL);
pthread_cond_init(&(thread_data->input_cond), NULL);

pthread_create(&producer_thread, NULL, produce_bytes, (void *) thread_data);
pthread_create(&consumer_thread, NULL, consume_bytes, (void *) thread_data);

pthread_join(producer_thread, NULL);
pthread_join(consumer_thread, NULL);
```

When I run this, `produce_bytes()` signals `consume_bytes()` successfully on the first iteration, but on the second and subsequent iterations, a signal is sent to `consume_bytes()` and it never gets heard, so the consumer function never gets run again:

```
PRODUCER ...signaling consumer...
PRODUCER ...consumer signaled...
CONSUMER ...consuming chunk...
CONSUMER ...chunk consumed...
PRODUCER ...signaling consumer...
PRODUCER ...consumer signaled...
PRODUCER ...signaling consumer...
PRODUCER ...consumer signaled...
PRODUCER ...signaling consumer...
PRODUCER ...consumer signaled...
...
```

I am using the tutorial [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) as the basis for what I'm trying to do. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the *outside-loop* for your consumer? You have one for your producer, but your consumer seems to only care about the first arrival. And your signaling mechanism could be cleaned up a bit as well. Look carefully at your consumption thread and ask yourself what happens after the predicate becomes true and that `while`-loop breaks. Is there *anything* present that will return us back to that predicate loop again?

Comment: If I try to `pthread_create` and join a new consumer thread within the `produce_bytes()` function, once I have bytes to consume, then the program hangs. Can you add an answer to suggest a way to fix this?

Comment: Is the intent to add an arbitrary number of consumers? It makes a difference. I've almost finished crafting a single/single example for you regardless.

Comment: Ultimately, there will be a chain of multiple producers and consumers: `P1 -> C1 -> P2 -> C2 -> ...` I'm just trying to figure out the basic example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with that code:

1. `produce_bytes` locks the mutex for the duration of the blocking call to `fread`. A general rule of thumb for responsive applications is to lock the mutex for as short periods as possible. You may like to read the input into a temporary buffer first, then lock the mutex and copy the data to the buffer shared between threads. Same applies to `consume_bytes` which holds the mutex while calling `fprintf` which can block.
2. `produce_bytes` in `while(d->n_bytes > 0)` does not hold the mutex, which is a race condition because `consume_bytes` assigns a new value to `d->n_bytes`. Assuming you would like to exit that loop when `fread` returns 0 (EOF), you need to copy the return value of `fread` into a local variable not shared between threads and use that as the condition in `while(read_bytes > 0)`
3. `consume_bytes` does not have any loop around it so that it returns after the first condition variable notification. You probably would like to wrap it into a `while` loop and exit only when EOF (0 bytes) have been read.

Comment: +1 nice answer. An example on coliru [**can be seen here**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6cdcdd228d000fe4). I addressed the issue of off-mutex reading the input buffer. Sorry for any typos or lame mistakes (a lack of sleep thing), but hopefully Alex gets the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example which addresses Maxim's point 2 and 3, but not 1 because that is necessary for responsiveness but not strictly for correctness.

Note that I have not implemented a means for the producer to signal EOF to the consumer, so the consumer will never exit.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define  BUF_LENGTH_VALUE 100
typedef struct {
    pthread_mutex_t input_lock;
    pthread_cond_t input_cond;
    unsigned char in_buf[BUF_LENGTH_VALUE];
    size_t n_bytes;
} pthread_data_t;

void * produce_bytes(void *t_data)
{ 
    pthread_data_t *d = (pthread_data_t *)t_data;

    size_t local_byte_count = 0;
    do {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&d->input_lock);
        local_byte_count = fread(d->in_buf, sizeof(unsigned char),
                BUF_LENGTH_VALUE, stdin);

        d->n_bytes += local_byte_count;
        if (d->n_bytes > 0) { 
            fprintf(stdout, "PRODUCER ...signaling consumer...\n");
            pthread_cond_signal(&d->input_cond);
            fprintf(stdout, "PRODUCER ...consumer signaled...\n");
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&d->input_lock);

        // This is added to slow down the producer so that we can observe
        // multiple consumptions.
        sleep(1);
    } while (local_byte_count >  0);



    return NULL;
}

void * consume_bytes(void *t_data) 
{
    pthread_data_t *d = (pthread_data_t *)t_data;
    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&d->input_lock);
        while (d->n_bytes == 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "CONSUMER entering wait \n");
            pthread_cond_wait(&d->input_cond, &d->input_lock);
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "CONSUMER ...consuming chunk...\n");
        d->n_bytes = 0;
        fprintf(stdout, "CONSUMER ...chunk consumed...\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&d->input_lock);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

}

int main(){
    pthread_t producer_thread = NULL;
    pthread_t consumer_thread = NULL;
    pthread_data_t *thread_data = NULL;

    thread_data = malloc(sizeof(pthread_data_t));
    thread_data->n_bytes = 0;
    pthread_mutex_init(&(thread_data->input_lock), NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&(thread_data->input_cond), NULL);

    pthread_create(&producer_thread, NULL, produce_bytes, (void *) thread_data);
    pthread_create(&consumer_thread, NULL, consume_bytes, (void *) thread_data);

    pthread_join(producer_thread, NULL);
    pthread_join(consumer_thread, NULL);
}
```